# Are Windows file permissions bound to the file, or the file system location?

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

Do Windows file permissions follow:

1. The file, or...
2. The file system location

Say I have a file at "C:\MyFile.txt".  I set some very specific permissions on this file.

Later, I copy a new file over the top of that one.  Same name, same file system location.

Does it inherit the same permissions, or does it bring its own permissions with it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the moment a file is created, it gets assigned those permissions marked as Inheritable-by-files from the directory it was created in. For the life of that file it will only change permissions if:

- Permissions are changed directly on the file itself
- A change higher up the directory-tree affects one of the Inherited permissions it already has (add or subtracts).
- A change higher up the directory-tree adds or removes an Inherited permission
- Higher up the tree an admin does a "replace all permissions to subordinate objects" push, which overwrites any permissions on the file with those the admin is pushing down the directory tree.

A critical thing to keep in mind is that *all NTFS permissions are explicit*. An inherited permission is a permission with an 'Inherited' flag set, but it is still that permission. For all but the top bullet point, Windows has to touch every single file below the point the inheritable-permission was changed in order to actually make the change.

This is why if you make a permission change at the top of a 5-million file directory-tree and hit the 'cancel' button in a panic, you have screwed yourself. For that permissions will be inconsistently applied across that 5-million file directory tree and the only way to fix it is to set the permission and let it complete application and then remove it again, or to do a 'force these permissions to everything below me' which'll remove any custom permissions below that point.

Anyway...

As noted elsewhere, moving a file within the same filesystem does not count as a 'create' so it retains whatever permissions it had when it started. A move between filesystems is a 'create' so the file will receive permissions based on where it is moved to.

Most applications consider an 'overwrite' to actually be a 'delete and re-create' which causes the overwritten file to receive inherited permissions based on its location. If the overwrite is actually, 'zero out the file and repopulate with new data' it isn't a create and will retain whatever permissions it had before the overwrite; applications that do this are rare.

Comment: Dude -- your comment about how moving a file from another filesystem is considered a "create" and not a "move" just resolved **15 years** of confusion for me.  Seriously.  You are my hero today.

Comment: @Deane Yaaay! This is why we do this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: you will lose the permissions settings, if you will replace the file with the new one (the new file will bring its own permissions - depend on which way will you use for moving it over the old one), and so it will do if you just copy the file somewhere else. It will not lose the permissions settings, if you will just rename it or move to a different directory.

See [How Permissions Work](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530(WS.10).aspx) on the technet and [Understanding Windows NTFS Permissions](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Understanding-Windows-NTFS-Permissions.html) for more details on the topic.

More specific explanation: http://www.tech-faq.com/ntfs-permissions-after-copying-or-moving-files.html (thanks kwbaker for the link)

The buttom-line:

> When a file is Copied, it will inherit
>   the permissions of the folder it is
>   copied to. If the file is Moved - it
>   will retain its original permissions
>   at its new location.
>   (Jeff Hengesbach)

Comment: When a file is Copied, it will inherit the permissions of the folder it is copied to.  If the file is Moved - it will retain its original permissions at its new location.

Comment: The only scenario in which permissions are preserved is when you move files or folders to a different location on the same NTFS partition.  Copying (on the same partition or between them) always replaces permissions with those that would normally be inherited at the destination, and moving between NTFS partitions has the same effect.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Alexey is correct -- although permissions are properties of files and directories (rather than locations), different methods of moving/copying can have different effects on those permissions.  [This page](http://www.tech-faq.com/ntfs-permissions-after-copying-or-moving-files.html) has a brief summary.